# df command on Centos/VirtualBox

Tags: centos, virtualbox, disk-usage, storage

I'm studing the use of df, when i tried it on centos 7 on my virtualBox, i got this :

```
df -h 
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                 1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                    1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    1.9G  9.6M  1.9G   1% /run
tmpfs                    1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/centos-root  8.0G  5.3G  2.8G  66% /
/dev/sda1               1014M  239M  776M  24% /boot
tmpfs                    379M   24K  379M   1% /run/user/1000
```

i don't understand from where all this space came from, because i have only 10G when i first created this VM, and 4G for the RAM, and in the configuration of the VM i get this :

[image]

```
Information when i click in storage  : 
type : Normal (VDI)
virtual size : 10G
reel size : 4.86
details : storage of differentiation
Emplacement : ...
attached to : centos (install snapshot)
```

Comment: `tmpfs` filesystems are virtual; see `man tmpfs` for a full explanation.

Comment: @ajgringo619 thank you for your response, i did a little search about it, i found it's a virtual space used for swap, so i should have maximum  4G of RAM and 10 G of storage i configured at the creation and not 17 G like it shows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df` shows all mounted filesystems, which include [tmpfs](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/tmpfs.5.html) virtual filesystems that reside in memory.

From your `df` output you have just two filesystems saved on disk:

- 1 GB `/boot` on `sda1` partition
- 8 GB `/` on `centos-root` logical volume

The remaining 1 GB from your disk is most likely used for swap which is not shown in `df` output (you can use `lsblk` to list block devices on your system, it will show swap too).

The content of remaining mountpoints you see (`/dev`, `/run`...) is stored in memory. These are special folders created dynamically by the OS (for example [`/dev`](https://tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/dev.html) contains special files that represent block and character devices in your system). RAM for these is allocated dynamically when needed, these don't actually take 2 GB of RAM each, the size is just an upper limit.